# Oracle database migration from on premise to AWS with zero downtime and only AWS services

Tags: oracle, amazon-web-services, migration, database-migration, aws-dms

I wanted to know if we can migrate an oracle database from on premise to AWS, using aws/open source tools/services only with zero downtime. The preference is just AWS services. since this is a 1 time requirement we are not interested in purchasing third party tool licenses. The important requirement for this POC is that there shouldn't be any downtime.

Kindly let me know if you can provide me any inputs for the same.

Thanks

Comment: You plan to use ORACLE RDS or Oracle on EC2 instance?.

Comment: Oracle on Ec2 instance... the size of the data to be transferred can be considered to be about 10GB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To reduce database downtime, use standby technology.

1. Install Oracle software only(same version on premise server) on the new server AWS EC2.
2. Perform a hot backup on the premise server.
3. Restore the hot backup to the new server AWS EC2.
4. Configure the standby between the premise Oracle servers
       and new AWS EC2.
5. Make switchover role primary to standby AWS EC2.

Comment: Why 11g? An extended support contract with Oracle will be required for support from Jan 2019. I would recommend going with the latest release.

Comment: There is no version in the question. 11g- this is just an example, so many companies use 11g.

Comment: Exactly. This answer does not read like an "example", it says, explicitly, "Install Oracle software **only 11g**" as if that's the best (or only) option.